# Run vba code on the selection of first listRow in excel

Tags: excel, vba

In a structured table when table is initially created the listRow is 0.
Let us say in `Sheet1` we have a listobject `Table1`
I need to run the following code:
`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True`.
when `Table1` has no rows and the first row is clicked or stepped in or any cell in the first row (The row after the header) is selected.

I need this because locked formula cell in protected sheet is not working unless there is at least 1 list row.

Problem Explained:

[image]

Comment: May I see your workbook?

Comment: @SiddharthRout: sure: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3fsLmazeoLCNldyU2c0ZXJJSGc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @SiddharthRout: To test....unprotect the sheet and create a 2nd row you will find the formula coming. protect the sheet and try to enter QTY and Price formula will not work

Comment: I just entered the values and it is working. It is giving me the total in last column

Comment: Are you sure your calculations are set to `Automatic` and not `Manual`? Check the `Formulas Tab|Calculation Options`

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Yes it is automatic..Look I added a GIF image explaining the problem..appreciate your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77984/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-mahmoud-tarief).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post Chat Discussion:

The problem was with the way you were creating the table and adding the formulas and protecting the sheet immediately after deleting the rows. Also you were trying to run the code on a protected sheet.

Try this

**Creation of the table**

I am taking the example of Cells `A1:C1`

A. In Cell A1, B1, C1, type "Header1, Header2, Header3"

B. Next Select A1:C1 and click on Insert | Table

C. Click on the Checkbox "My Table has headers"

D. Next in Cell C2, type the formula

```
=IF([Header1]+[Header2]=0,"",[Header1]+[Header2])`
```

E. Protect the sheet keeping Col C locked and A/B unlocked.

And you are done.

Use this code to add new rows

```
Sub Sample()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Unprotect 
        .ListObjects("Table1").ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True
        .Protect
    End With
End Sub
```

Remember when you reset the table by deleting the rows, ensure that you type something in cell A2 and B2 and then clearing the cells before you protect the sheet else you will loose your formulas.

Hope this helps

Comment: For your first example..Let us assume there is a formula in column `Header4` which sums `header 1, 2 and 3` values. `Header4` is protected and locked while `Header 1, 2 and 3` are not locked. When user will enter the values of `Header 1, 2 and 3` unfortunately `Header4` will not auto calculate to sum 1, 2 and 3 for some reason I don't know why. It will only calculate if I add `.ListRows.Add` so that's why I want whenever `listRow` is zero, run `.ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True` once user touches the row.

Comment: The problem of the formula not auto calculating for structured table when formula cell is protected is actually driving me crazy. I'm searching this one day back and nobody ever mentioned such weird bug.